# Vue FireStore Reactive Key Assignment - Object is possibly 'undefined'

Tags: javascript, typescript, firebase, vue.js

I am attempting to assign FireStore `data()`, forwarded by `props`, to a `reactive()` proxy object, but am receiving the following error:

```
Object is possibly 'undefined'.
(property) fireStoreData: Record<string, any> | undefined
```

I wish to use a `forEach` loop instead of direct assignments i.e. (`pageForm.name = props.fireStoreData?.name`) to minimize code.

```
props: {
    fireStoreData: Object,
}
...
setup(props){
    ...
    const pageForm: { [key: string]: any } = reactive({
        name: '',
        address: '',
        ...
    })

    onMounted(() => {
        Object.keys(pageForm).forEach(key => {
            if(key in props.fireStoreData)                  // <-- error found here
                pageForm[key] = props.fireStoreData[key]    // <-- and here
            })
        })
    })
    ...
}
```

Comment: @Dharmaraj Unfortunately, that's not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issie is that the fireStoreData prop is not required yet in your code you assume it is.

try:

```
props: {
    fireStoreData: {
        required: true,
        type: Object
    }
}
```

If you dont want the prop to be required, its always possible to check for it being defined and add a watcher to look for changes.

Also, dont forget props can change in value.

// on mobile, will format later on pc

Comment: That worked beautifully. Thank you. If you don't mind, please try taking a look at this question...
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68203084/vue-3-component-reset-does-not-reset-reactive-object-data

Comment: @RyanPrentiss Answer to the linked question is correct. You need to actually take emit as a parameter to the setup function for it to be accessible (different from vue2)

Comment: Well, this is awkward. I didn't notice someone had answered it. Lol